# What is the hot flow and cold flow in coroutines and the difference between them?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am mastering Kotlin coroutines and trying to figure out

1- what is hot flow and cold flow ?

2- what is the main difference between them?

3- when to use each one?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

A cold stream does not start producing values until one starts to collect them. A hot stream on the other hand starts producing values immediately.

I would recommend to read below to understand hot and cold steams with usage:

https://balwindersinghrajput.medium.com/complete-guide-to-livedata-and-flow-answering-why-where-when-and-which-6b31496ba7f3

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow

Answer (score 13):

Hot flow :
Events will be emitted irrespective of listener's presence.

*Real life example*

You got stuck in traffic trying to get to the cinema to see Barbenheimer. The movie would begin, and the projectionist wouldn't wait for you.

Cold flow : Events will be emitted only in the listener's presence.

*Real life example*

You want to watch Spiderman ATSV, which is on demand, on your television. It will be played for you at your request i.e when you subscribe.

Comment: Surprisingly good analogy

Answer (score 9):

Form Here ([+](https://dev.to/coroutinedispatcher/what-i-learned-from-kotlin-flow-api-4gp))

> Cold vs Hot streams
>
> Well, I really struggled with this concept because it is a little bit
> tricky. The main difference between cold and hot happened to be pretty
> simple: Hot streams produce when you don’t care while in cold streams,
> if you don’t collect() (or RxJava-s equivalent subscribe()) the stream
> won’t be activated at all. So, Flows are what we call cold streams.
> Removing the subscriber will not produce data at all, making the Flows
> one of the most sophisticated asynchronous stream API ever (in the JVM
> world).

Answer (score 9):

1. **Cold** flows are created on-demand and emit data when they’re being observed. **Hot** flows are always active and can emit data regardless of whether or not they’re being observed.
2. The main difference is that a **cold** flow is a type of flow that executes the producer block of code on-demand when a new subscriber collects. A **hot** flow is always active.
3. See examples of usage in Manuel Vivo's articles from "Google Android developers" group:

- [A safer way to collect flows from Android UIs](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda)
- [Things to know about Flow’s shareIn and stateIn operators](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/things-to-know-about-flows-sharein-and-statein-operators-20e6ccb2bc74)

Answer (score 5):

Cold flow is what you need if the flow needs one collector. It does not get triggered unless there's a collector. Each collector has its **own** instance of the underlying cold flow. It gets collected and it's done & gone.

Hot flow, on the other hand, does not really care too much about if it's being collected or not at that very moment. It's always around (in memory) till it's GC'ed and emits events from possibly multiple coroutines. If parties are interested in, they can subscribe by calling `collect`, and **all** collectors will get the **same** event  emitted from that hot flow. Much like an event bus.

Unlike cold flows, hot flows are always in memory even tho when there's no subscribers/collectors and they're active by default. Cold flows are lazy.. However, hot flows are better for sharing a state across multiple observers.

If you have multiple collectors to share a single state, then you can opt for state flow where a potentially heavy background operation is avoided.

You can expose a cold flow to your UI layer (i.e.: to a view model) and then turn it to a hot flow (for example, using `shareIn`) which then gives you the benefit of scoping the hot flow to the view model.

Answer (score 3):

##### Cold Flow:

A flow is called "cold" because every time a terminal operator is called on the flow (ex. `collect`) it needs to execute the producer code.

##### Hot Flow:

On the other hand, a "hot" flow doesn't need to execute any code when it's collected because holds the latest state in memory.

Also, cold flows only emit when there's a collector while hot flows don't  care about it and always emit.