# How to use database as source of truth for text state while updating TextInput quickly using MutableState?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow

In my Jetpack Compose app, I use Room to store a list of TODO items that each have an editable text. I would like to have the database as single source of truth (providing a flow of task lists), but updating the DB asynchronously for each character [leads to issues](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/effective-state-management-for-textfield-in-compose-d6e5b070fbe5).

I would like to use a `MutableState` to "cache" the text input and

- update the DB whenever the cache doesn't change for a while (could be done by converting the cache `MutableState` to a flow and using `debounce`)
- update the cache when text is entered by the user, but also when the DB changes. **How can this be achieved?**

This is what I have come up with until now:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TasksScreen(viewModel = ...) {
  val tasks: List<String> by viewModel.tasks.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
  LazyColumn {
    items(items = tasks) { index, task ->
      Task(text = item, onTextChanged = { viewModel.setText(index, it) })
    }
  }
}

@Composable
fun Task(text: String, onTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
  val textState = remember { mutableStateOf("") }.apply { value = text }
  val textUpdateFlow = remember {
    snapshotFlow { textState.value }.debounce(1000).onEach { onTextChanged(it) }
  }
  BasicTextField(
    value = textState.value,
    onValueChange = { textState.value = it },
  )
}
```

Problem: whenever `textCache` is updated the `Task` composable is recomposed, but this means that the original text overwrites the text the user has typed, so the text field stays the same. Also I am not sure if defining and remembering the textUpdateFlow in the composable is correct and which scope the flow has.

Answer (score 0):

A solution for this problem is to make use of different [recomposition scopes](https://www.jetpackcompose.app/articles/donut-hole-skipping-in-jetpack-compose#recomposition-scope), creating the text `MutableState` in a different scope than where it is read. The following is a generic snippet that can be used if a composable needs a fast cached state that should update and be updated by a slower outer state (e.g. a DB).

```kotlin
@Composable
fun <T> CachedUpdate(
  value: T,
  onValueChanged: (T) -> Unit,
  debounceMillis: Long = 1000,
  content: @Composable (MutableState<T>) -> Unit,
) {
  // this will run whenever a new value comes in from the outside (e.g. from DB)
  val cached = remember { mutableStateOf(value) }
  cached.value = value
  LaunchedEffect(onValueChanged, debounceMillis) {
    snapshotFlow { cached.value }.debounce(debounceMillis).onEach(onValueChanged).collect()
  }
  content(cached)
}
```

It can then be used like so:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Task(text: String, onTextChanged: (String) -> Unit) {
  CachedUpdate(text, onTextChanged) {
    // this will re-run whenever the cached text is updated
    val (cachedText, setCachedText) = it
    BasicTextField(
      value = cachedText,
      onValueChange = setCachedText,
    )
  }
}
```

**Here's how it works:**
The `CachedUpdate` composable creates and remembers a cached state. On (re-)composition, this state is updated with the newest value passed into `CachedUpdate`. The cached state object is then passed to the child composable, which can read and update it. Whenever the cached state is updated, **only the child composable is recomposed**, because it has its own recomposition scope. This means we avoid re-running the `CachedUpdate` composable which would result in overwriting the cached state. To write changes to the cached state back to the DB in a debounced manor, we convert it to a flow and use the `debounce` method. For each update, we invoke the provided callback to write the data into the DB. Note that we still need to collect the flow because `snapshotFlow` is a [cold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69297362/what-is-the-hot-flow-and-cold-flow-in-coroutines-and-the-difference-between-them) flow. As this is a suspend function, we need to properly scope it, so it will be cancelled when our `CachedUpdate` composable (and the included text field) leave the composition. This can be done using [LaunchedEffect](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect). To make sure we create a new flow if any of its parameters change (debounce time and callback), we pass those as key to the `LaunchedEffect`.